# Why can't Pattern match "/*!"?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match something and for the life of me I cannot figure out WHY it does not work as expected.

String: `"/*! preserved */"`

Pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("(/[*][!](?:.+?)[*]/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)  
- FAIL
```

Pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("(/[*](?:.+?)[*]/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) 
- PASS
```

I only want to catch comments that have a `!` right after the opening comment string.  I even tried reducing the match to just `/*!`:

```
Pattern.compile("(/[*][!])", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) 
- FAIL

Pattern.compile("(/[*!]{2})", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
- FAIL

Pattern.compile("(/[*][!])", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
- FAIL


Java Version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT**

This fails, which does not make sense to me since my pattern does not have a start or end with a requirement:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/[*]!.+?[*]/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is a test /*! preserved */ this is a test /*! preserved1 */");
System.out.println("Pattern: " + p);
System.out.println("Group: " + m.group(1));
System.out.println("Found: " + m.find());
```

Even reducing it to just match `/*!` fails:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/[*]!)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is a test /*! preserved */ this is a test /*! preserved1 */");
System.out.println("Match: " + m.find());
System.out.println("Pattern: " + p);
System.out.println("Group: " + m.group(1));
```

Comment: `*` is a special character, escape it like so `\\*`

Comment: @Doorknob putting `*` in `[]` like he did makes it match a literal `*`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/[*]!.+?[*]/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL
            | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println(p.matcher("/*! preserved */").matches());
```

output

```
true
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to tweek it a bit, and I am still confused as to why m.find() returns false, but I updated my code to use m.matches()

Comment: As matter of fact, your pattern #1 works fine for me as is for both find and matches. I just wanted to show that it works and also that expression can be simplified a bit. I dont know how come it does not work for you

Comment: It does not match if you add any text before or after the comment

Comment: @Digitalxero, if you use `.matches()` then the whole input must be matched.  To find a matching substring in a larger string use `.find()`.

Comment: find does not seem to work either, if you look at my last example in my original post

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the javadoc for [`matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

> ```
> public boolean find()
> ```
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the `start`, `end`, and `group` methods.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if, and only if, a subsequence of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Find starts searching from the end of the last match. Not from the beginning of the String. This is the reason `m.find()` returns false.

You can see this behavior with this example.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(/[*]!.+?[*]/).*", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is a test /*! preserved */ this is a test /*! preserved1 */");
//System.out.println("Match: " + m.matches());
//System.out.println("Pattern: " + p);
//System.out.println("Group: " + m.group(1));
System.out.println("Found: " + m.find());
```

This returns true. However if you the uncomment the other lines, `m.find()` will return false.

If you called `m.reset()` before calling `m.find()` you will be able to tell if the pattern is anywhere in the string. However this resets the state of the matcher which might not be desirable.

**Edit:**

To find all matches by just using find use the following code. (Notice the missing `.*`)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(/[*]!.+?[*]/)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is a test /*! preserved */ this is a test /*! preserved1 */");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output

```
/*! preserved */
/*! preserved1 */
```

Since `Matcher.matches()` must match the whole string you need a slightly more complex regex to find all the matches which is probably undesirable.

Comment: The thing is that OP's pattern consume the whole string (note the `.*` behind), and also the `.*` in front, so there is no way he can find all matches. Even if you use `find()`, the problem is not solved.

Comment: @FDinoff Just to make it complete, I think you should also point out that `matches()` have to match the whole string to return `true`. Also that one needs to call `reset()` after calling `matches()` as well (before calling `find()`).

Comment: @nhahtdh I edited the post to show how to find all the matches with `find()`

Answer (score -2):

One example based on String API itshelf for validating Password.

```
    String password = "Velu1!";
    String pattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=_-])(?=\\S+$).{6,100}$";
    if (!password.matches(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valid Password!");
    }
```

In this case your pattern is

```
  String pattern = "(/[*]!.+?[*]/)";
```

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: @MikeSamuel This is alternative for Java pattern/matcher in String API i newly learned. For those who is troubling with usage of pattern / Matcher; they can simply use String API only.